# How to test AngularDart components?

Tags: angular, testing, dart

I try testing some component:
https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/000e233092b6781128a8488cbbb7a051

```
dependencies:
  angular2: '^3.0.0-alpha+1'
  angular2_components: '^0.4.0-alpha'

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test:
   git: "https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_test.git"
   version: '^1.0.0-alpha+5'
  test: '^0.12.20+2'


@Component(selector: 'page-view', templateUrl: 'page_view_component.html')
class PageViewComponent {}

@AngularEntrypoint()
void main() {
  test('Should create a new component in the DOM', () async {
    NgTestBed testBed = new NgTestBed<PageViewComponent>();
    NgTestFixture fixture = await testBed.create();
    expect(fixture.rootElement.innerHtml, contains("PageViewComponent"));
  });
}
```

When I run **pub run test -p dartium** command I get failed test:

```
00:02 +0 -1: test/client/components/page_view_test.dart: Should create a new component in the DO
M [E]
  Cannot find reflection information on ApplicationRefImpl
  package:angular2/src/core/reflection/reflection.dart 24:7     NoReflectionCapabilities.factory
  package:angular2/src/core/reflection/reflector.dart 85:37     Reflector.factory
  package:angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.dart 130:27  resolveReflectiveFactory
  package:angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.dart 156:8   resolveReflectiveProvider
  dart:_internal                                                ListIterable.toList
  package:angular2/src/core/di/reflective_provider.dart 163:60  resolveReflectiveProviders
  package:angular2/src/core/di/reflective_injector.dart 363:12  ReflectiveInjector.resolve
  package:angular2/src/core/di/reflective_injector.dart 392:58  ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCre
ate
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart 35:42                 bootstrapForTest
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 192:14             NgTestBed._createDynamic.<fn>
  dart:async                                                    Future.Future.sync
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 190:16             NgTestBed._createDynamic
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 171:12             NgTestBed.create
  page_view_test.dart 17:43                                     main.<fn>.<async>
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                                    Future.Future.sync
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 190:16             NgTestBed._createDynamic
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 171:12             NgTestBed.create
  page_view_test.dart 17:43                                     main.<fn>.<async>
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                                    Future.Future.microtask
  page_view_test.dart                                           main.<fn>

00:02 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

When I run **pub run angular_test:test**, I get:

```
Could not find bin/test.dart in package angular_test.
```

When I run **pub run angular_test** and open Dartium, in console I get:

```
00:00 [32m+0[0m: Should create a new component in the DOM[0m
(program):1 00:00 [32m+0[0m[31m -1[0m: Should create a new component in the DOM [1m[31m[E][0m[0m
(program):1   NoSuchMethodError: Class 'DynamicComponentLoaderImpl' has no instance method 'loadAsRootIntoNode'.
  Receiver: Instance of 'DynamicComponentLoaderImpl'
  Tried calling: loadAsRootIntoNode(Type: class 'PageViewComponent', Instance of 'ReflectiveInjectorImpl', overrideNode: Instance of 'HtmlElementImpl')
(program):1   dart:core                                              Object.noSuchMethod
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart 75:37          _runAndLoadComponent.<async>
  dart:async                                             _ZoneDelegate.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:21     NgZone._run
  dart:async                                             _CustomZone.bindCallback.<fn>
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 162:11     NgZone._scheduleMicrotask.<fn>
  dart:async                                             _ZoneDelegate.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:21     NgZone._run
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                             _Completer.completeError
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart 90:1           _runAndLoadComponent.<async>
  dart:async                                             _ZoneDelegate.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:21     NgZone._run
  dart:async                                             _CustomZone.bindCallback.<fn>
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 162:11     NgZone._scheduleMicrotask.<fn>
  dart:async                                             _ZoneDelegate.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:21     NgZone._run
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart                _runAndLoadComponent
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart 47:12          bootstrapForTest.<fn>
  package:angular2/src/core/application_ref.dart 314:26  ApplicationRefImpl.run.<fn>
  dart:async                                             _ZoneDelegate.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:21     NgZone._run
  dart:async                                             _CustomZone.run
  package:angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 305:23     NgZone.run
  package:angular2/src/core/application_ref.dart 312:10  ApplicationRefImpl.run
  package:angular_test/src/bootstrap.dart 46:17          bootstrapForTest
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 192:14      NgTestBed._createDynamic.<fn>
  dart:async                                             Future.Future.sync
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 190:16      NgTestBed._createDynamic
  package:angular_test/src/frontend/bed.dart 171:12      NgTestBed.create
  page_view_test.dart 17:43                              main.<fn>.<async>
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
  page_view_test.dart                                    main.<fn>

(program):1 00:00 [32m+0[0m[31m -1[0m: [31mSome tests failed.[0m
(program):1 
page_view_test.html:1 Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Dummy exception to set exit code.
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1138)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)
#3      _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:49306)
page_view_test.html:1 Observatory listening at http://127.0.0.1:33685/
```

How it can be testing?

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/issues/62

Comment: Have you tried `pub run angular_test`? Also ensure the transformer configuration matches the one shown in https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_test

Comment: Yes, I tried pub run angular_test.

Comment: "Could not find bin/test.dart in package angular_test." sounds weird. Can you try `pub cache repair` and `pub upgrade --packages-dir` and then again `pub run angular_test`?

Comment: I do `pub cache repair`, then `pub upgrade --packages-dir`. And remove .pub in directory, then `pub get` but trouble still remains. `Could not find bin/test.dart in package angular_test.`

Comment: What version for `angular_test` does your `pubspec.lock` contain? The file in `angular_test/bin` is named `angular_test.dart` instead of `test.dart` your error complains about.

Comment: I use `angular_test: '^1.0.0-alpha+5'`

Comment: `pub run angular_test:test` should just be `pub run angular_test` (without `:test`) or `pub run angular_test:angular_test`

Comment: Yes, when I use `pub run angular_test` I can open Dartium and see in console: `NoSuchMethodError: Class 'DynamicComponentLoaderImpl' has no instance method 'loadAsRootIntoNode'.` `Receiver: Instance of 'DynamicComponentLoaderImpl'`, `Tried calling: loadAsRootIntoNode(Type: class 'PageViewComponent', Instance of 'ReflectiveInjectorImpl', overrideNode: Instance of 'HtmlElementImpl')`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that error. I haven't tried the angular_test package yet myself.

Comment: How you test angular components and services?

Comment: I stopped testing components because it was changing too frequently how testing in Dart Angular2 worked and didn't get back to it yet :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going back to angular2 version 3.0.0-alpha. angular_test is still work in progress and will need an update to work with 3.0.0-alpha+1.

Comment: Yes, with updated package all work good. It would be better if it supported automatic testing like: `xvfb-run pub run test -j 1 -x aot -p dartium`